# Insert data in Multidimensional array in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, multidimensional-array, collections

I am writing an API in laravel and i want to send the data to front end to be shown in a table. I want insert data in an array and then send it.

Bellow is the screenshot of table in which i want to fill the data

[image: Financing Table]

Can anyone help me with this. Been stuck on this for 2 days.

Comment: Hello @Huzaifa. Welcome to StackOverflow. I think you missed the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) part. Have a second look at it so people can answer you professionally and precisely.

Comment: Do you want multidimensional associative array?

Comment: Kindly explain your question a bit more

Answer (score 0):

This is how you make a multi-dimensional array in PHP:

```
$array = [];
$array[] = ['one', 'two'];

// Or just
$array = [
    [
        'one', 'two'
    ]
];
```

And so on and so on. You could also just get the model you want in a collection and call the `toArray()` function on it.

Comment: I want it to be in key value pairs how can i do that ?

Comment: `$array = ['key' => 'value]`. Read up on the docs, this is all in there: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

Basically i wanted a response something like this.

```
"amount_received": {
            "0": {
                "loan": {
                    "amount_m_1": null,
                    "amount_m_2": null,
                    "amount_m_3": null,
                    "amount_m_4": null,
                    "amount_m_5": null,
                    "amount_m_6": null,
                    "amount_m_7": null,
                    "amount_m_8": null,
                    "amount_m_9": null,
                    "amount_m_10": null,
                    "amount_m_11": null,
                    "amount_m_12": null,
                    "amount_y_1": null,
                    "amount_y_2": null,
                    "amount_y_3": null,
                    "amount_y_4": null,
                    "amount_y_5": null
                }
            },
            "amount_m_1": null,
            "amount_m_2": null,
            "amount_m_3": null,
            "amount_m_4": null,
            "amount_m_5": null,
            "amount_m_6": null,
            "amount_m_7": null,
            "amount_m_8": null,
            "amount_m_9": null,
            "amount_m_10": null,
            "amount_m_11": null,
            "amount_m_12": null,
            "amount_y_1": null,
            "amount_y_2": null,
            "amount_y_3": null,
            "amount_y_4": null,
            "amount_y_5": null
        }
```

After a bit of searching i am able to achieve this thing bellow is the code about how to do it.

```
$financing=array();

    $amount_received_arr=array();
    for ($j = 1; $j < 13; $j++) {
        $amount_received_arr['amount_m_' . $j] = null;
    }
    for ($j = 1; $j < 6; $j++) {
        $amount_received_arr['amount_y_' . $j] = null;
    }

    $temp_arr=array();
    for ($j = 1; $j < 13; $j++) {
        $temp_arr['amount_m_' . $j] = null;
    }
    for ($j = 1; $j < 6; $j++) {
        $temp_arr['amount_y_' . $j] = null;
    }

    $amount_received_arr[0]=['loan'=>$temp_arr];
    $financing[0]=['amount_received'=>$amount_received_arr];
```

Sorry about the question as i couldn't explain my problem well enough anyhow thanks for the help everyone.